# Responsive columns(display: table) doesn't work with Safari, Safari(mobile) and Chrome(mobile)

Tags: css, responsive-design, safari, multiple-columns, css-tables

I'm trying to make responsive columns with "display: table" and this is what I've come up with.

http://jsfiddle.net/ejkim2000/NXmfk/

html

```
 <body> 
 <section id="colors"> 
   <ul id="columns">
        <li class="red">red</li>
        <li class="yellow">yellow</li>
        <li class="blue">blue</li>
   </ul>
</section>
</body>
```

css

```
body { height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ccc;
}
#colors {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}
#columns {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#columns li {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-row;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    }
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    }
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    }
@media only screen and (min-width: 479px) {
    #colors {
    height: 320px;
    width: 100%;
}
#columns li {
    display: table-cell;
}    
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #colors {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
#columns li {
    display: table-row;
}    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    #colors {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
#columns li {
    display: table-cell;
}    
}
```

It's working well with Firefox, IE9, and Chrome(Desktop) whether I rotate the presentation of the browsers or resize the window. It doesn't show any problems.

However, it shows very weird behavior with Safari(desktop), Safari(mobile), and chrome(mobile). It shows proper columns in the beginning but once I rotate the screen or resize the window, it's basically adding one or two more empty columns. If you resize my jsfiddle example above with safari, you'll get the idea or this [image](http://www.ejkimdesign.com/column_examples.jpg) shows how it does:

I've been searching the answers, but nobody seems to have the same problem as I have.

Could you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: I can confirm that there is something fishy in at least version 7 of Safari when trying to run responsive `display: table-cell` `li`s... Could this be a Safari bug?